# Internal build configuration during project development - good practices

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros, c++17

*First of all sorry for the vague title. If someone comes up with a better one feel free to change it.*

I'm developing a c++ library in Visual Studio and during development I want to be able to change some internal build configurations (for easier testing, tracing, etc.), i.e. compile code for sequential instead of parallel execution (easier debugging).

The way I'm doing it right now is by defining some macros in a separate header file:

**BuildConfig.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#ifdef _DEBUG 
    #define MM_DEBUG true
#else
    #define MM_DEBUG false
#endif

// temporarily overrules _DEBUG
#define MM_DEBUG true

#define MM_PARALLEL true
#define MM_DEBUG_SEQUENTIAL (MM_DEBUG && !MM_PARALLEL)

#if MM_PARALLEL
    #define MM_EXEC_POLICY std::execution::par
#else
    #define MM_EXEC_POLICY std::execution::seq
#endif
```

The only problem I have with using a header file is that I have to include it in basically every source (or header) file to make the macros available. But when I forget to include that header somewhere those source files are not build correctly (as all the `#if` statements will evaluate to false because the macro does not exist in that file).

Is there a way to *export* all the macros from **BuildConfig.hpp** to the command line, so that the macros become available project wide (like `_DEBUG` or `__cplusplus`)?

Is this even a good practice? Are there better ways (in terms of good practice) to achieve what I want?

### Edit

I've found a way to include the **BuildConfig.hpp** header in each file using the **FI** flag (forced include). It's located at *project properties > C/C++ > Advanced > Forced Include File*

Comment: I remember a question where someone wanted to get a warning or error on missing defines and the solution was to add parentheses to the macros so they are "functions without arguments". These do not implicitly become false. Unfortunately I cannot remember the title.

Comment: @PaulR That's kinda nice and hacky at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The `_DEBUG` macro is available project wide because it is defined in project properties page in Visual Studio. I am not sure it there is a possibility to export macros from *.hpp to cmd (as far as I know it is not possible). As you tagged your question with Visual Studio, I assume that this is the only IDE that you are using and you don't care for portability.

When it comes to Visual Studio there are property sheets which are designed to hold whole configuration for project. They are separated by build type (e.g. debug, release, x64, x86). I think that it might be good idea to use them. You can read more about it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx). IMHO I think it is better than holding all of that in some source file, but this is only my opinion.

I am not sure if this is better way. As in case of many C++ libraries there are often a lot of macros used in similar manner to what you have written like checking compiler version, and switching some things if `_DEBUG` is defined. Other thing to choose might be using CMake which holds build configuration but this will be almost the same as Visual Studio Property Page (but just more portable to other OS).

Important thing never do this kind of hack because someday you will forget to remove it and it will cause troubles for others

```
// temporarily overrules _DEBUG
   #define MM_DEBUG true
```

Comment: I've already thought of property sheets. But afaik, preprocessor conditionals (`#if`) cannot be specified in property sheets (like I did with `MM_EXEC_POLICY`). That's why I'm not using it already. To the `MM_DEBUG` macro: I know it's hacky but sometimes I have to build in release mode (because in debug it would be incredibly slow) but still have to generate some additional output. That's why I'm overwriting it sometimes.

Comment: Actually you can still use property sheet. If you don't have many of those `#if ` (like only for Parallel ) you can just create another build configuration.

Comment: And how would I do that? I don't want to explicitly define the macro in each config.